# Can you prove a strong law of large numbers? A weak law?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

(Allan Gut, Probability: A graduate Course) Suppose $X$ and $\{X_k, k\geq1\}$ are independent, identically distributed random variables, such that

$$P(X=n)=\frac{1}{n(n-1)},\;\;\text{for}\;n=2,3,...$$

Can you prove a strong law of large numbers? A weak law?

I have no idea about it. Any hint please. Thanks!

Comment: I have a strong feeling information is missing.

Comment: If the random variables are iid and the expectation exists (even if it is infinite, like in this example) then both the strong and weak laws hold. This is a very nontrivial theorem though.

Comment: @MathQED Well, it is posted as an exercise in the book mentioned (Pg 325, Chapter 6)

Comment: @Mark any ideas on how to prove them?

Comment: Let $a>0$ and $e_a$ the expected value of $min(X,a)$. Let $Y_n=min(X_n,a)$, then the $Y_n$ are iid with expected value $e_a$ and thus the SLLN applies and $Y_1+\ldots+Y_n =n(1+o(1))e_a$ almost surely. Thus almost surely $X_1+\ldots+X_n\geq n(1+o(1))e_a$. Thus as the liminf of $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$ is greater than $e_p$ for every integer $p$. But the sup of the $e_a$ is infinity (monotone convergence theorem), which concludes.

Comment: @af13 The general theorem is very difficult, I don't think you are supposed to use it here. Maybe there is a direct proof for this specific sequence, if I'll find one I'll write it.

Comment: @Mindlack why the result follows from the inequality?

Comment: @Mark Great. Thank you so much.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274917/a-problem-about-strong-law-of-large-numbers-of-shiryaevs-probability?rq=1

Comment: Well, you know that almost surely, for all integers $p > 0$, $(X_1+\ldots+X_n) \geq n(1+o(1))p$, thus if $n$ is large enough $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n \geq p-1$. So $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$ goes to infinity and we’re done (or aren’t we?).

Answer (score 0):

If you prove that $\lim_ {n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Var(X_{k})=0$ then you prove that $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}{n} \rightarrow^{P} E(X)$, in this case the weak law.

You can see that $\forall n \geq 2$:

$E(X)=E(X_k)=\dfrac{1}{n-1}$

$E(X^2)=E(X_k^2)=\dfrac{n}{n-1}$

$Var(X)=Var(X_k)=\dfrac{n}{n-1}-(\dfrac{1}{n-1})^2=\dfrac{n(n-1)-1}{(n-1)^2}$

Then;

$\lim_ {n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Var(X_{k})=\lim_ {n \to \infty}  \dfrac{1}{n^2}  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{n(n-1)-1}{(n-1)^2}=\lim_ {n \to \infty} \dfrac{n(n-1)-1}{n(n-1)^2}= 0$

With this:

$P(|\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}{n}-E(x)|>\epsilon) \leq \dfrac{Var(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}{n})}{\epsilon^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Var(X_{k})}{\epsilon^2}$

If you tends to infinity , you find that:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}{n}-E(x)|>\epsilon)=0$

Therefore, $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}{n} \rightarrow^{P} E(X)$ and verifies weak law.

This is similar for strong law, you have to use almost sure convergence.